# Spring-Boot: how to check if Mongock has completed?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongock

I'm using Mongock for migrating and initializing my MongoDB database with Spring-Boot.
What I need is a way to check when all the changelogs have been applied.

How can I check if Mongock completed all the changelogs/changesets?

I found that Mongock creates a collection **mongockLock** in which there is an entry while the migration is running.

Would it be enough to check for the absence of any document in the above collection to conclude that Mongock has completed the changelogs?

How can I query for the documents in this collection?

Answer (score 1):

first at all, the `mongockLock` collection is just the collection for the distributed pessimistic lock. It's the mechanism Mongock uses to ensure that a changeLog is only run by an instance at a time. If it's successful, just once(unless flag runAlways is true, in which case will obviously run every time).
**So mongockLock is not what you are looking for**

There are 3 ways you can check your migration has run successfully, or not.

1. Do nothing. If you don't change the default value of `failFast` in any ChangeSet, the **Mongock runner** will throw an exception if any of the changeLogs fails
2. Subscribing to the Mongock events. You can check [this example project](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock-examples/tree/version4/mongoDB/version4_x/spring5-springdata3/src/main/java/com/github/cloudyrock/mongock/events)
3. Checking the collection **mongockChangeLog**

Comment: I guess the Mongock events is the only option since I want to use it to then run other tasks on the data that has been inserted through the changesets. I need to run a task via @Scheduled() just after the application is started and the changelogs completed, then once per hour.

Comment: If it's a springboot application, you can do that without events. By making setting the runnerType(by configuration with mongock.runner-type, or builder with buildInitializingBeanRunner), the application won't startup if mongock fails.

Comment: How should I set the mongock.runner-type? InitializingBean or ApplicationRunner?
Without configuring it, the @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000L) method is executed the first time before 'Mongock has finished' is logged on the console.

Answer (score 1):

With spring boot, there are two approaches to use Mongock, like shown in [Mongock's documentation](https://www.mongock.io/quick-start):

1. Via **properties**, using `@EnableMongock`

   ```yaml
   mongock:
     runner-type: InitializingBean
   ```
2. With the **builder** approach

   ```java
   @Bean
   public MongockInitializingBeanRunner mongockInitializingBeanRunner(
                                          ApplicationContext springContext,
                                          MongoTemplate mongoTemplate){
   return MongockSpring5.builder()
       .setDriver(SpringDataMongo3Driver.withDefaultLock(mongoTemplate))
       .addChangeLogsScanPackage("your_changeLog_package_path")
       .setSpringContext(springContext)
       .buildInitializingBeanRunner();
   ```

}

- The schedule job shouldn't happen before Mongock, if runner-type is InitializingBean. However it may happen if it's ApplicationRunner

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. I am using the @EnableMongock approach. I annotated the method with @ EventListener and @ Scheduled so that it is executed right after migration success and once every hour.